# How to make my website faster with slideshow background

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, performance

I'm working on a website with slideshow as a background. There are a bit more than 40 photos, which totally weights 110MB. Too much for a website - but I want those photos to be seen in Full HD. I know that my website will be slow, but I would like to hear some advices how to make the website faster, for example running the photos in PHP file that will return it in the exact height and width of the screen.

Here is my current code for the slideshow:

```
        var images = [];
        var str = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 41; i++) {
            images[i] = 'image/bg/'+ (i + 1) +'.jpg';
        };

        function preloadImg(src) {
            $('<img/>')[0].src = src;
        }
        function shuffle(array) {
          var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;
          while (0 !== currentIndex) {
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
          }
          return array;
        }
        $.each(shuffle(images), function( index, value ) {
            preloadImg(value);
            str += "<div style='background-image: url("+ value +");' class='background"+ (index + 1) +"'></div>";
        });
        $("#background").append(str).children("div:gt(0)").hide();
        setInterval(function() { 
            $('#background > div:first').fadeOut(1000)
                                        .next()
                                        .fadeIn(1000)
                                        .end()
                                        .appendTo('#background');
        },  10000);
```

Comment: @dawez But the slideshow is in the index

Comment: I mean upload photos with smaller quality maybe 90% this 10% down reduced file size a lot of and effect is same as 100% quality. Next think I mean is use on background CSS3 style "background-size:cover;" and upload photo with smaller resolution (for example 1600x1200px smaller image have smaller size and this CSS style grow resolution of image for full HD monitors = growing lost some quality but not so much if used 1600x1200 not 400x300 ).

Comment: You can already reduce the file size of your images quite a bit without changing resolution. Try imageoptimizer.net .

Comment: As stated by the above comments - lower the resolution. You can easily lower it 75% (compressing) without losing any visible detail.